# Call class method by string name as callback of a native function within another class method

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, associative

I know this question has been asked before, but not in this context (OOP):

```
class XYZ {

    public function index() {

        $array = [
            [
                'id' => 1,
                'name' => 'Alpha'
            ],
            [
                'id' => 2,
                'name' => 'Beta'
            ],
            [
                'id' => 3,
                'name' => 'Gamma'
            ]
        ];

        $newArray = usort($array, 'modify');

        return $newArray;

    }

    public function modify($a, $b) {

        return $b['name'] - $a['name'];

    }

}
```

This indexAction returns an empty array, and I am not sure why.

Comment: This is a multi-problem page that probably won't serve as a good signpost to other pages.  How to use a class method as a callback is well covered and the common misconception that sorting functions return a useful payload is also well covered.  I'll support the deletion of this page as the answers are not high value either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over here within your `usort` function the second parameter consist of two values first one `ClassName` and the other one `functionName` so your second parameter looks like as

```
usort($array,['ClassName','functionName']);
```

Which in your case it'll be like as

```
usort($array,['XYZ','modify']);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/438228)

Answer (score 3):

ksort — Sort an array by key

```
bool ksort ( array &$array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR ] )
```

Sorts an array by key, maintaining key to data correlations. This is useful mainly for associative arrays.

```
<?php
$fruits = array("d"=>"lemon", "a"=>"orange", "b"=>"banana", "c"=>"apple");
ksort($fruits);
foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = $val\n";
}
?>
```

The above example will output:

a = orange
b = banana
c = apple
d = lemon

For more info : http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php

Comment: This answer appears to completely ignore the asked question.  This answer's score is perplexing.

Answer (score 1):

Because `usort` returns a boolean http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php . You want to return the modified variable `$array`

Comment: If you want your code to run, please change the question to "Please fix my code so that it works". I answered the current question.